# "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression." - unnecessary console.log?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jshint.com, I'm getting the following error: "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression."

On this line: `(headerTop != parseInt($('#content').css('margin-top').slice(0, -2))) ? $('#content').stop().animate({'margin-top': headerTop}, 150) : console.log('');`

What can I do to get rid of this error?

**Here is that line in context:**

```
function resize() {
    var headerTop = $('#masthead').outerHeight();
    (headerTop != parseInt($('#content').css('margin-top').slice(0, -2))) ? $('#content').stop().animate({'margin-top': headerTop}, 150) : console.log('');
}
resize();
window.onresize = resize;
```

Comment: Did you find this page? http://jslinterrors.com/expected-an-assignment-or-function-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSLint docs could cast some light on the problem: http://jslinterrors.com/expected-an-assignment-or-function-call

Bascially, what you get is a warning, informing you about the possibiliby of a typo or unnecessary code. This kind of warnings can be supressed via JSHint configuration option - `expr`. Take a look here: http://jshint.com/docs/options/#expr.

Quick solution is to drop the ternary operator you're using, and simply use an `if ... else` statement. Between us, what you wrote in the `resize()` function is reaaaally not readable ;)

Comment: How would I clean that up? I actually got help from someone on here awhile back and I'm not as proficient in JS so any help would be appreciated. Thanks for the ternary tip. I will try to see what I can do with that newfound knowledge.

Comment: As I wrote, try changing `(headerTop != parseInt(......` into `if ((headerTop != parseInt(....)) { // stuff } else { console.log('') }`. JSHint will have nothing against a standard `if ... else` structure.

Comment: In my case there wouldn't be an `else` right? Since the only thing within the `if` statement is `$('#content').stop().animate({'margin-top': headerTop}, 150)` Keep in mind that I don't need the `console.log` anymore.

Comment: Your code from the post has `: console.log('')` in it, which is an equivalent of `else`. But yeah, I don't think you need the `else` either.

Comment: @J82 Conditional expressions are not if-else statements. If you need an if-else statement, use an if-else statement.